# Fault in script to separate a sentence into individual variables

Tags: javascript, html

There is a fault somewhere in this script. I have narrowed down the issue to either the part of the script that splits the string into variables, or the part that places `w1` back into the textbox, although when I enter `""` in place of `w1` it properly deletes all content in the text box. I have only included the necessary snippets below. I am sure that the documents are properly linked, and there are no interferences between this and other functions.

```js
function myFunction() { //yeah I gotta use funtion myFunction... it's hilar.
  var x = document.getElementById("translateinput").value;
  var w1 = x.split(" ")[0];
  var w2 = x.split(" ")[1];
  var w3 = x.split(" ")[2];
  var w4 = x.split(" ")[3];
  var w5 = x.split(" ")[4];
  var w6 = x.split(" ")[5];
  var w7 = x.split(" ")[6];
  var w8 = x.split(" ")[7];
  var w9 = x.split(" ")[8];
  var w10 = x.split(" ")[9];
  var w11 = x.split(" ")[10];
  var w12 = x.split(" ")[11];
  var w13 = x.split(" ")[12];
  var w14 = x.split(" ")[13];
  var w15 = x.split(" ")[14];
  var w16 = x.split(" ")[15];
  var w17 = x.split(" ")[16];
  var w18 = x.split(" ")[17];
  var w19 = x.split(" ")[18];
  var w20 = x.split(" ")[19];
  document.getElementById("translateinput").value = w1;
}
```

```html
<div id=thing>
  <br>
  <textarea type="text" id="translateinput">Enter text here to translate!</textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="translate" onclick="myFunction()">Translate!</button>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

the line `var w15 = x.split(" ")[14;` does not contain the closing of the hook "]".

To detect this kind of error you have to use a debugging tool there are several especially those that are integrated in browsers like Chrome for example you go to the menu (Tools / Development tools)